# How to use shared variable in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
 class xyzController extends Controller
 {  
   public $a;
   public function index(Request $request){
           $input =Request::all();
           print_r($input);
           $this->a =$input;

           return view('page_name', compact('array_name'));
   }

   public function abc(){
          print_r($this->a);
   }
}
```

My code in Laravel looks like this. It's not working. I want to use some variable in function abc() which is initialized in function index(). Here variable $a is public type and initialized in function index() as 
`$this->a =$input;` and accessing it in function abc() as `print_r($this->a);`
I can not call to function index() in function abc() as it's returning to some other pages, while function abc also returning to some other pages which is different from index().

Can someone correct me where it goes wrong in accessing variable $a in function abc() or can suggest me the better way to access $a in function without using global variable?

Comment: I think this should be `$request::all()`

Comment: No, it's working fine even My question is accessing variable .. you can initialized $input anything Say $input ="Hello World".

Comment: How do you access `abc()`?

Comment: This function is used by some other page which is already routed in route.php. Question is how to access this variable in function abc() ?

Comment: Why not use that as a parameter?

Comment: Can not use as parameter because function abc() also not going to call in function index() as function abc() is directly routed in route.php and index is also routed for two different functionalities.

Comment: When redirect just pass that as a parameter in your blade.

Comment: Can you write the syntax ?

Comment: Can you show me also the html and the other back end regarding to your question?

Comment: Route.php is like-
Route::get('index', xyzController@index);
Route::get('index', xyzController@abc);

and my controller is already you know and there is need of any html or view cause already it's redirected by route.

Comment: try to add `exit;` in your function abc. Did that return something?

Comment: So do you want to passed that in your view?

Comment: No, I want to pass this variable just in abc function where I can print simply as print_r($var); That is you can see my code also.

Comment: Then `$var = $this->a;` lastly `print_r($var);`

Comment: Already done bro ..it's not working that is the problem I asked.

Comment: Try to make that as static: `public static $a;` then `$test = self::$a`

Comment: then tell me how do I initialized $a in index function and after that use this variable in function abc.

Comment: Also the same `self::$a = $input;`

Comment: It's also not working .

Comment: Can you print `$index` variable values in your `index` function without any error?

Comment: yeah .. I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
class xyzController extends Controller
{  
   public function index(Request $request){
     $input =Request::all();
     session()->put('requestData',$input);
     print_r($input);

     return view('page_name', compact('array_name'));
   }

   public function abc(){
     print_r(session('requestData'));
   }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this approach (functional though) is that for testing purpose you will be relying on the Request class, where as if you use dependency injection and inject the Request object, then you can test your controller with it.

Comment: Yes, rohit for my case it's not good idea to do this way because all request I am taking in index function itself and it have many conditional statement for different condition for redirectly in different pages. So can you tell me the better way to do this same act.

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad You should use session for that.

Comment: Can you write or tell more about session syntax ?

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad If you want the data to be gone after accessing abc function, just put one more line after the print statement in abc function

`session->forget('requestData');`

Comment: It shows following error even after I have route in Middleware.
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Comment: Still the error
Class App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Http\Request does not exist
 I am already using this use Request; so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Not exactly same error, I wrote the error in my above comment.

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad Can you write your use statements and namespace written before class?

Comment: @RohitKhatri , I'm repeating my question again that I want to use a variable in a class which will get initialized in one function and print their value in another function. In c++ this is really so easy, but how can I do this same in php?

Comment: this is all my namespace and use statement before the class::

'namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;
use DB;
use Request;
use View;'

Comment: Please replace this `use Request; ` with `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`. And if only want to know how to use variables assigned in one function, in other function you don't need to access request.

You must resolve your request issue first, here's the reference for request:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad Where you able to access Request::all() before the solution?

Comment: this is in index function and I want to use this value in abc function as you can see in my problem statement in top of page.

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad Did you replace `use Request;` with `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` ?

Comment: When I replace this then it runs but it can not take input and it show error that Why I do like this.

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad I have updated the answer, try this out now, but before that, just remove everything you added from my previous solution and restore your code to your state.

Comment: @RohitKhatri this comes to me initial problem, It don't display anything when I call to function abc(), I know it should print the same as in index function printing. this is actual problem ..Can you please fix it ?

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad Well in that case, I need to access your machine or you can put your code on any of your server and give access to me.

Comment: Sorry bro, I am working on live project for some private company. I can not share my whole code or machine ..but really thanks and I appreciated you help.  However I am trying to solve this too hope I'll find solution when I will get the I will let you now my solution to this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad I can give you access to my machine with laravel installed, and you can type dummy code in that specific to your problem. And I would be able to fix.

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad Don't you have skype?

Comment: yeah , I have we can chat there only cause video calling is not working on ubuntu.

Comment: That's ok, here's my skype name `developer.rohitkhatri`

Comment: @RohitKhatri, problem is solved, problem was in version of laravel. Since I'm using the laravel 5.2 so in this version when you use cookies, session request like that you have to route everything in Middleware route, Otherwise it will return null values without any error.

Comment: @BaidyanathPrasad ohh got it.